# MYSQL - Join 2 tables with full rows on left table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

I have 2 tables as below:

**attributes**

```
| id | name         |
|----+--------------|
| 1  | first_name   |
| 2  | last_name    |
| 3  | email        |
```

**attribute_values**

```
| uid   | attr_id   | value     |
|-------+-----------|-----------|
| 1     | 1         | Hello     |
| 1     | 2         | world     |
|-------+-----------|-----------|
| 2     | 1         | A         |   
| 2     | 2         | B         |
| 2     | 3         | a@xzy.com |
```

I want to write a query to select attributes of a user even if attribute is not exist in table attribute_values. Then, I would like to get result with null value.

For example for selecting user id 1

```
| name          | value     |
|---------------|-----------|
| first_name    | Hello     |
| last_name     | world     |
| email         | NULL      |
```

user id 2

```
| name          | value     |
|---------------|-----------|
| first_name    | A         |
| last_name     | B         |
| email         | a@xzy.com |
```

user id 3 **(not exist in attribute_values)**

```
| name          | value     |
|---------------|-----------|
| first_name    | NULL      |
| last_name     | NULL      |
| email         | NULL      |
```

Is there best way with one query to get result as 3 above examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.value
FROM    attributes a
        LEFT JOIN attribute_values b
            ON a.ID = b.attr_id AND b.uid = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afabf/3)

Comment: Not sure about ` AND b.uid ` what does it do? - edit- nevermind.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, it's a typo